# npm 'json-update' is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, electron

We are using npm `json-update` to update `json` files in electron application. Its working fine in local environment as we have the project in 'D', 'E' or some other drives, but once we installed the application we can't able to update the `json` file which is in 'C' drive. When we try to read the `json` it throws error like this,

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program
>   Files...........\product.json.lock'    at Error (native)

and while write the `json` it throws error like this,

> Error: Problem saving JSON file: EPERM: operation not permitted, open
>   'C:\Program Files...........\product.json'
>       at C:\Program Files...........\node_modules\json-update\lib\json-update.js:92:23
>       at C:\Program Files...........\node_modules\lockfile\lockfile.js:61:41
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the problem is about permission. Delete product.json.lock and try again, otherwise u need to contact your system administrator

Comment: Actually we don't have such file called 'product.json.lock', its been created at run time and deleted immediately.

Comment: then u need to contact your system administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that two instances won't try to update the same json file, you could hack json-update to remove the use of lockfile. It appears to be at line 42 and line 90: https://github.com/runvnc/json-update/blob/master/lib/json-update.js#L42

However, if the problem is that the application doesn't have permission to create/modify files under C:\Program Files then doing this might just get you to the next failure. It feels like a better solution is to have your app install its data JSON files to the application data folder (`app.getPath('userData');`), and then modify them there. Looking at the above code, it appears the lockfile gets made in the same directory as your json file, so if you follow this approach you shouldn't need to hack json-update either.

Comment: Hi @Darren Cook,
Thanks for the suggestion.